# tabs in Jquery UI 1.8 to 1.9 no longer working

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have updated the jquery UI from 1.8.2 to 1.9.2, i have created my own custom css styling for the tabs. However, after updating the library, the tabs do not function as they did in 1.8.2

please see my code:

```
<div id="tabs_leads_new">
<ul>
    <li class="group"><a href="overiew.php"><img src="images/tab_icon_place_holder.png"  class="side_bar_icon"/></a></li>
<li class="group" onclick="$('#leads').slideToggle()">All</li>
<div class="closed" id="leads">
<li class="group"><a href="today.php">Today</a></li>
<li class="group"><a href="yesterday.php">Yesterday</a></li>
</div>
<li class="group"><a href="aged.php">aged</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now when i remove the div with class closed, the tabs work fine, but when i leave the div the tabs do not load.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is not valid, you can't have a `<div>` inside of an `<ul>`.

Comment: Hi, when you say you cant have a div inside a ul, is that because of strict html, or is it because its not allowed by the div or is it because, its allowed due the strict ui tabs semantic as it did work perfectly before when using ui 1.8.2, also can you suggest how else i could go about this.

Comment: Well, it's just not possible in HTML standard. Don't know why it used to work with older jQuery versions. Please edit your question and add more details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thorsten, the tabs are style as vertical tabs, and the li with the onlcick function has hidden li's inside the div with class group, when the user clicks on the li that has an onlick the hidden li's then become visible with the jquery effect.

Comment: Thorsten, thanks solution was simple in first place, not sure why i made it complicated!!!! thannks for putting me the right directtion